# Entity Framework relationships not loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I generated my `DbContext` and entity types using the [`Scaffold-DbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext) command in powershell.

I can successfully retrieve records from the database however, the relationships always seem to be `null`.

**Asset.cs**

```
class Asset
{
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual AssetCategory Category { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

The relationship configuration appears to be OK in the `DbContext` file that was automatically generated.

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.Category)
    .WithMany(p => p.Assets)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CategoryId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
    .HasConstraintName("FK_Asset_AssetCategory");
```

What I do note is that the `Constraints` folder within the database for the `Asset` table is empty?

**Example usage**

```
// basic properties of asset are correctly hydrated here, just not relationships
var asset = await _dbContext.Assets.FindAsync(id);

// category is always null
var category = asset.Category;
```

This happens with all the relationships defined on the entity model and I don't understand why?

Comment: We absolutely need to see how you get `asset` or we can't help.

Comment: @DavidG Updated my question to include how I am obtaining an `Asset`.

Comment: You haven't told the context to include the category so it won't get it. Do this: `_dbContext.Assets.Include(a => a.Category).FindAsync(id);`

Comment: @DavidG `FindAsync` doesn't exist when I do that. However, I replaced that with `_dbContext.Assets.Where(a => a.id == id).Include(a => a.Category).FirstOrDefaultAsync();` and that has worked. I had expected calling `Category` on a loaded `Asset` would obtain it but apparently not. If you want to add your suggestion with the amendment as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: What you expect to happen here is *lazy loading*. EF should be configured explicitly to enable that. But don't enable lazy loading without thoroughly contemplating the pros and cons. I consider it an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from [`DavidG`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663001/davidg) pointing out I needed to use the [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-6.0) method to load the relationship(s) as they are not automatically lazy loaded.

```
var asset = _dbContext.Assets
                      .Where(a => a.id == id)
                      .Include(a => a.Category)
                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```